# Using "sed" to find and replace a non atypical string

Tags: command-line, sed

I need to use `sed` in the terminal (no other option, I'm afraid) and I need to find and replace all sequences of four or more digits (no white spaces) with a specific word "brad". I have tried and tried to understand the manual but it is just so bad.

How do I do this? And while I am looking for the exact command, I would appreciate an explanation of why it works the way it does (the exact command used here that is).

Comment: already answered, but if you want to learn about sed...you might find this more informative then the man pages: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-sed2/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{4,\}/brad/g' infile
```

Explanation:

```
s/regex/replacement/flags
[0-9]              # Any digit.
\{4,\}             # Matched more or equal to 4 times.
brad               # Substitute matched string with literal 'brad'
/g                 # Apply it globally: Many times for each line.
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get the s/[0-9]/brad/g before posting, but \{4,\} ... is that generally true in shell commands ? or is it "just here" ?

Comment: @Kalec: It depends. There are several regex flavours but syntax should be similar.